# How to add Divs inside a div but float them to left?

Tags: css, html

I have this html code

```
<div id="b_container">
    <div id="b_header">
        <div class="header_left"><a href="#">link 1 </a></div>
        <div class="header_left"><a href="#">link 2 </a></div>
        <div class="header_left"><a href="#">link 3 </a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="b_content">content goes here</div>
    <div id="b_footer">footer goes here</div>
</div>
```

I used this css code

```
#b_container
{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: red;
    width:900px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#b_header{
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;

}
.header_left{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    background: #CCCC00;

}
#b_footer{
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}
#b_content{
    background: #00FFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

but the result shows the three divs (with class header_left) above the `b_content`. why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the floating from the `div`s (with class `header_left`). You can do it with adding following line to `#b_header`:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WsjPM/).

An alternative is to add an empty div with `clear: both;` as last one in the div with id `b_header`. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WsjPM/2/).

Answer (score 0):

> but the result shows the three divs (with class header_left) above the
>   b_content. why ?

This is because you are not clearing the floats, you can do so by using `overflow:hidden` property or adding a div with `clear:both` property as the last child of the parent `div` 
container.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with flaots, you need to clear them, just create a `div` with this css: `clear: both`.

That should do the trick.

See more about floats [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)